# Solr OR query on a text field

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

How to perform a simple query on a text field with an OR condition? Something like `name:ABC OR name:XYZ` so the resulting set would contain only those docs where name is exactly "XYZ" or "ABC"
Dug tons of manuals, cannot figure this out.
I use Solr 5.5.0

***Update***: Upgraded to Solr 6.6.0, still cannot figure it out. Below are illustrations to demonstrate my issue:

1. This works:

[image: works]

2. This works too:

[image: works too]

3. This still works:

[image: still works]

4. But this does not! Omg why!?

[image: does not work omg why]

Comment: OMG it's like that in SolrJ (scala) too!     

`solrQuery.setQuery(s"""sku:(${skus.mkString(" ")})""")` - does not work      
      
`solrQuery.setQuery(s"""*:* AND sku:(${skus.mkString(" ")})""")` - works! Lucene why do you do this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wacky workaround I've just come up with:

[image]

Comment: Less wacky query that works: `+sku:(13576609 13576610)`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to perform OR query. Below I have listed some of them. You can select any of it.
 
[**Simple Query**]

```
q=name:(XYZ OR ABC)
```

[**Lucene Query Parser**]

```
q={!lucene q.op=OR df=name v="XYZ ABC"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is right, but what you're asking for isn't what text fields are made for. A text field is tokenized (split into multiple tokens), and each token is searched by itself. So if the text inserted is "ABC DEF GHI", it will be split into three separate tokens, namely "ABC", "DEF" and "GHI". So when you're searching field:ABC, you're really asking for any document that has the token "ABC" somewhere.

Since you want to perform an *exact* match, you want to query against a field that is defined as a `string` field, as this will keep the value verbatim (including casing, so the matching will be case sensitive). You can tell Solr to index the same content into multiple fields by adding a copyFile instruction, telling it to take the content submitted for field `foo` and also copying it into field `bar`, allowing you to perform both an exact match if needed and a more general search if necessary.

If you need to perform exact, but case insensitive, searches, you can use a KeywordTokenizer - the KeywordTokenizer does nothing, keeping the whole string as a single token, before allowing you to add filters to the analysis chain. By adding a LowercaseFilter you tell Solr to lowercase the string as well before storing it (or querying for it).

You can use the "Analysis" page under the Solr admin page to experiment and see how content for your field is being processed for each step.

After that querying as `string_field:ABC OR string_field:XYZ` should do what you want (or `string_field:(ABC OR XYZ)` or a few other ways to express the same.